# Why is scaling text evil?

Tags: best-practices, scaling

The TikZ & PGF manual says that

> It is possible to transform nodes, but, by default, transformations do
>   not apply to nodes. The reason is that you usually do not want your
>   text to be scaled or rotated even if the main graphic is transformed.
>   Scaling text is evil, rotating slightly less so.

Why is scaling text evil?

Comment: How about *not* creating a new tag for each term used in your question, but looking for appropriate existing tags?

Comment: @lockstep: Thank you for fixing the tags.  I did find best-practices, but I wasn't sure about the rest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scaling text is evil because it makes your font size inconsistent. The philosophy of TeX is to keep a consistent style through the whole document.

Comment: I don't see how that applies to text within figures, which is where you typically use TikZ. Or am I wrong?