# Resizing table when using package {threeparttable}

Tags: tables, scaling, adjustbox, threeparttable

I'm using the `{threeparttable}` package because I want to use table notes, but I'm having a problem resizing my tables. If I use `{adjustbox}` to enclose `{tabular}` (or `{tabularx}`), I get an error message:

> ```
> ! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders. \caption@hrule
> ->\hrule 
>                     \@height \z@  l.23 \end{tabular}}
> ```

The same applies if I use `\resizebox` or `\scalebox` at the same point in the code.

If I use `{adjustbox}` and enclose `{threeparttable}`, the code runs, but the fontsize of the caption and table note are also scaled down...

[image]

... which is not what I want!

Does anyone know a way to resize the table font only when using package `{threeparttable}`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[a4paper, bindingoffset=0.5cm, tmargin=2.4cm, bmargin=3.4cm, lmargin=3.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm, footskip=2.4cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
This is some text which refers to Table~\ref{tab:Table}
\begin{table}
\centering
% \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Table caption.}
\label{tab:Table}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{10}{c}@{}}
\toprule
Item & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 & Col 5 & Col 6 & Col 7 & Col 8 & Col 9 & Col 10 & Col 11 \\
\midrule
Some sort of stuff\tnote{a} & 107.5 & 5.62 & 89.1 & \num{14367.7} & 3.4 & 21.9 & 112.6 & \num{18644} & 432.4 & 17 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item[a] This sort of stuff is only available in winter.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
% \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158864/why-is-scaling-text-evil

Comment: I'm not unduly surprised, I thought it all seemed rather too good to be true! Still, occasionally it's fun to flirt with the dark side...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`threeparttable` wants to see `tabular` and `tablenotes` at the outer level, not buried into `adjustbox`.

Thinks *very* carefully before deciding to scale a table. For instance, a body text of 14pt is humongous and will make the scaled table disappear with respect to the text.

I reduced to 11pt, which is a quite large font size.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[a4paper, bindingoffset=0.5cm, tmargin=2.4cm, bmargin=3.4cm, lmargin=3.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm, footskip=2.4cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
This is some text which refers to Table~\ref{tab:Table}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table caption.}
\label{tab:Table}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{10}{c}@{}}
\toprule
Item & Col 2 & Col 3 & Col 4 & Col 5 & Col 6 & Col 7 & Col 8 & Col 9 & Col 10 & Col 11 \\
\midrule
Some sort of stuff\tnote{a} & 107.5 & 5.62 & 89.1 & \num{14367.7} & 3.4 & 21.9 & 112.6 & \num{18644} & 432.4 & 17 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item[a] This sort of stuff is only available in winter.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Would I scale also the caption? No way.

Comment: Many thanks @egreg. Like a lot of things, it seems easy when you know how! I'm not really using a 14-point font, I just used it in the example to make the scaling more obvious, and to make it clear that the caption font was being downsized too.

Comment: PS What's the alternative to scaling if one has a lot of columns, is it just a question of adjusting the table font size manually?