# Threeparttable - overfull hbox

Tags: tables, threeparttable

When utilizing the `threeparttable` environment, I frequently encounter `Overfull \hbox` warnings, even when the table's content does not extend beyond the specified line boundaries.

A MWE is provided below.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{\lipsum[1][6-8]}
  % \resizebox{.8\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \textbf{Notation} & \textbf{Description} \\
      $a$     & \lipsum[1][1] Dumy \\
    \end{tabular}
  % }
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[A] \lipsum[1][3-5]
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

EDIT.
The same issue appears if I put the `tabular` environment inside a `resizebox` (you can test the behaviour by uncommenting the commented lines). I know that it is not always the best approach, but I want also to stress the issue related to the `threeparttable` environment. In this case, indeed, it seems that even if the `table` itself has the proper size, the `tablenotes` still stretches outside the boundaries.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `threeparttable`. You simply have too much content in `tabular`. You should use e.g. a `p` column.

Comment: Try changing `\begin{tabular}{cc}` to `\begin{tabular}{@{} cc @{}}`.

Comment: @Mico that worked! Can you explain why in an answer?

Comment: @campa the content of the second column is not larger than the content of the caption.

Comment: @tigerjack the content of the table is wider than the text width if you include the tabcolep padding on each column. Mico suggests using `@{}` to remove the padding on the outer edges (which gives you 12pt more space)

Comment: @tigerjack - Please see the answer I posted a short while ago.

Comment: You wrote, in a coda to your query, "I know that [`\resizebox`] is not always the best approach". In fact, it's rather well known that `\resizebox` is almost always the *worst possible approach*. Do you really want to gain a reputation among the readers of your working papers that you despise them so much that you're eager to spring `\resizebox`-ed tables on them?

Comment: @Mico :D Not at all, but I'm eager to understand how can make things go so bad when combined with `threeparttable`. Additionally, I think it may be useful for future readers.

Comment: @tigerjack - Please see the comment I posted below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `\begin{tabular}{cc}` to `\begin{tabular}{@{} cc @{}}` removes the whitespace padding that LaTeX otherwise inserts by default at the left and right hand edges of the `tabular` environment. For the material at hand, this happens to "work" (but only just!), in the sense that the overall width of the `tabular` environment no longer exceeds `\textwidth, making the overfull-line typographic slugs disappear. However, this is really just happy coincidence, and it's certainly far from robust.

What you really need is a setup in which the contents of cells in at least one of the table's two columns are allowed to wrap automatically. To eliminate tedious guesswork reagrding possible column widths, I suggest you load the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package and employ the eponymous `tabularx` environment instead of the `tabular` environment. The width of the X-type column(s) is determined by LaTeX as a residual.

By the way, the `\caption` statement is one of the three formal parts of a `threeparttable` environment; the other two are a `tabular`-like environment and the `tablenotes` environment. Hence, do include the `\caption` statement in the `threeparttable` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{\lipsum[1][6-8]}

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{}}
\toprule
Notation\tnote{A} & Description\tnote{B} \\
\midrule
$a$ & \lipsum[1][1-4]   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[A] \lipsum[2][1-4]
\item[B] \lipsum[2][5-9]
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason I put the `caption` outside the `threeparttable` is to be also able to resize the table using a `resizebox` (as per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205525/80949). However, even with the smaller table provided by the `resizebox` environment, the `tablenotes` environment still exceeds the borders (check the updated answer).

Comment: @tigerjack - One of the main reasons for employing a `tabularx` environment with a target width of `\textwidth` is to make it unnecessary to engage in `resizebox` and `adjustbox` shenanigans. Hence, if you follow the `tabularx` route, you still have no good reason for placing the caption outside the `threeparttable` environment...

Comment: for sure, and it'll be my preferred choice right now. I guess what I'm bothered about `threeparttable` is how it makes the `tablenotes` produce an overfull box even if you resize the `table`. And I was wondering if you had any explanation or guess on the reason.

Comment: @tigerjack - It happens because, bluntly put, you keep insisting on doing it all wrong. The point of the `threeparttable` machinery is to measure the width of the tabular-like environment (say, `A`) and then to set the widths of the caption and of the tablenotes environment not to exceed `A`. Crucially, the width of the tabular environment is measured *before* `\resizebox` gets applied. By failing to employ a `tabularx` environment (with a target width of `\textwidth`), `A` and therefore the width of the `tablenotes` env. exceed `\textwidth`. You have nobody but yourself to blame for that.

Comment: I'd like to reiterate that I no longer intend to use the `resizebox` command. My primary goal here is to enhance my understanding of LaTeX, particularly in the context of the `threeparttable` package combined with `resizebox`/`adjustbox`. Furthermore, as you may have noticed from the linked answers, many users are already employing `adjustbox`/`resizebox` in conjunction with `threeparttable`. Given this, I believe it would greatly benefit the community if you included your insights in the answer itself. This way, you can help alert future users to potential pitfalls and mistakes to avoid.

Comment: @tigerjack - I must admit that it took me a very long time before I caught on that what you were really struggling with, in the context of the `threeparttable` machinery, is how come that the width of the `tablenotes` environment could exceed `\textwidth` even though you were using the `\resizebox` sledgehammer.  Please post a new query, in which you mention up front that you're getting unfortunate outcomes when employing a `threeparttable` environment in this fashion. That way, your query will be seen by many more people.